# AVAssetImageGenerator generates an image with slightly wrong colors, but only on iOS 13.X

Tags: swift

It seems that AVAssetImageGenerator().copyCGImage generates an image with slightly wrong colors on iOS 13.x. The colors are correct on iOS 12.4.

Have anyone else experienced this?

---

**What it looks like**

1 = AVPlayer (Correct color)

2 = AVAssetImageGenerator result

*Notice how the background colors are slightly different.*

[image]

---

**Code**

```
extension AVPlayer{
    var poster: UIImage? {
        guard let asset = self.currentItem?.asset else {
            return nil
        }

        let videoFrameCGImage = try! AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset).copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 10), actualTime: nil)

        return UIImage(cgImage: videoFrameCGImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because the pixel buffer uses YUV colorspace but CGImage uses RGB colorspace?

Comment: That was my initial thinking too. But it doesn't explain why it performs as expected on 12.4.

Comment: Another idea I had that is you don't really have control over the exact point in time or algorithm by which the image is derived; it is an amalgam of frame info in the general area. So maybe it is extracting some material from neighboring frames that have a lighter color.

Comment: The background color never changes in the original video. I've so far tried probably 10 different timestamps, it's always the same color.

Comment: Can you provide a movie that demonstrates the issue, along with complete instructions? How are you "seeing" the image extracted in `poster`?

Comment: I would check the `renderingIntent`, `colorSpace` and `pixelFormatInfo` on both iOS versions for the CG Image. The asset generator itself may also have different settings.

Comment: Another comment would be the new `AVAssetExportPresets` for iOS 13, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avfoundation_constants)

Comment: Note that there were several new color spaces introduced in iOS 13, such as [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/kcgcolorspaceitur_2020_hlg) or [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/kcgcolorspaceitur_2020_hlg?language=objc). Apple doesn't say what's the default color space for `CGImage` is so I guess it could vary, on iOS version as well as by device.

Comment: From your diagram, the lighter images suggest H.264, to H.265 encoding differences

Comment: @AugustBjornberg did you manage to fix this? I have exactly the same issue (slightly darker video in AVPlayer on iOS 13 and iOS 12 as well)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue when generating thumbnails, and Pranav's comment above was the hint I needed. Copying the output `CGImage` into device RGB colorspace does the trick for me:

```
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
let thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, preferredTimescale: 30)
generator.maximumSize = maxSize ?? CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
var cgImage = try? generator.copyCGImage(at: thumbTime, actualTime: nil)

// This was the missing line - correct the color space
cgImage = cgImage?.copy(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB())

if let cgImage = cgImage {
     return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}
```

This changed the `cgImage.colorSpace` from using:

```
<CGColorSpace 0x28248f660> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; HDTV)
```

to using:

```
<CGColorSpace 0x282484120> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this Adam. The project has been on the back burner for some time but just got picked it up again, sorry for the delayed response. Your colorSpace addition worked beautifully. Many thanks!

Comment: after using this my page got more darker, I am using iPhone 11 Pro with iOS 16,

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work on my device. (iPhone 6s, iOS 13.7). Regardless of changing the colorSpace images are "greenish".